# How to pass query string to marketo smart campaign

Tags: marketo

I have a marketo landing page which is opened in incognito mode. The url looks like this: 
`https://go.marketo.org/page.html?email_value=email@domain.com`

This page has hidden marketo form that is being automatically submitted when page loads...

I have to pass the value of the email_value param to the smart campaign, so that to change one checkbox value in lead which has this email...

I tried the query string filter, but then I don't know how to identify lead based on the value sent to the marketo form.

Many thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did there with querystring 'is' email will not catch the actual querystring (parameter). If you're using 'IS', you'll need to use the full parameter e.g. 'email_value'.